# Debugging security rules for Cloud Firestore

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

I am setting up security rules for my `Google Cloud Firestore` database. I am trying to allow deletion of a document only if its timestamp value is more than 30 days in the past using the following logic:

```
allow delete: if
   resource.data.locked == false
   && (request.time - resource.data.timeStamp).seconds > 2592000;
```

When I try this I get `Error: Missing or insufficient permissions`. So, first question - am I going about this wrong or is my logic flawed?

And as a followup question, is there a way to debug rules? Perhaps a `console.log` equivalent whereby I can see the result of conditional rules as they are applied and check that I'm not submitting a string in place of a timestamp or anything daft like that?

I'm assuming that `request.time` is 'now' and that my `resource.data.timeStamp` is correct and that one minus the other returns a `Duration` and that `thatDuration.seconds` is returning a `number` but I'm a newb to this and any one of those assumptions could be wrong and it would be great to be able to see these values as they are processed.

Cheers all

Comment: did you tried `duration.value()` [doc](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/security/#duration)

Comment: I cant wait until this thing gets a debugger

Answer (score 0):

I am not checked, please try something like this

```
request.time < resource.data.timeStamp + duration.value(30, "d");
```

And your second question, i don't know. There is no simulator like in Realtime database. Remember its still in beta.

Answer (score 0):

There's now a [local emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/emulator-setup) to help debug Firestore rules. It won't allow you to step through the rules like a "real" debugger, but it'll at least give you more flexibility to test and verify which rules are broken.